# Reading resource from jar isn't working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, jar, resources, packaging

I'm attempting to create an executable jar for a selenium test.  Part of the things the code needs to do is set a system property to tell Selenium where the driver executable can be found (I'm using the chromedriver).  File structure is as follows:

```
src
   com
      mycompany
           SeleniumTest.java
   chromeDriver
      windows
         chromedriver.exe
```

And the code is as follows:

```
private static String WINDOWS_DRIVER = "/chromeDriver/windows/chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    SeleniumTest.class.getResource(WINDOWS_DRIVER).getFile());
```

When executed in eclipse, this code works fine.  However, when I export to a runnable jar file (from eclipse) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable 
    does not exist: F:\temp\file:\F:\temp\seleniumTest.jar!\chromeDriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:139)
```

And yet seleniumTest.jar exists at `F:\temp` as does the path within the jar which the error message specifies.

Any ideas on what is wrong or suggestions to try?  I've tried changing the slahses to backslashes and also (just as a test) hard coding the path (e.g. setting the system property to `F:\temp\seleniumTest.jar!\chromeDriver\windows\chromedriver.exe`), but neither has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system property is supposed to contain the path to the **file**, on the **file system**, where the driver can be found and executed.

The driver is not a file. It's an entry of your jar file. Executables bundled in a jar file can't be executed.

If you really want to bundle the driver into your jar file and execute it, then you'll have to read the bytes from this classpath resource, write them to a temporary executable file, and then tell selenium where this temporary executable file is located.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wasn't aware of that restriction.  I was following [this post](http://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/bundling-chrome-driver-with-your-test-code/) for guidance which suggested _"instead well get the path by using the Class.getResource which will enable us to bundle Chrome Driver inside our test framework even if it is bundled into a jar file."_  Is this wrong?

Comment: I think so, yes. Moreover, if it expected a URL, and  not a file path, it wouldn't work either because you're calling `getFile()` on the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
// locate chromedriver in the jar resources
URL res = getClass().getResource("/chromeDriver/windows/chromedriver.exe");
// locate chromedriver in the jar filesystem
File f = new File(res.getFile());
// copy chromedriver out into the real filesystem
File target = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + f.getName());
java.nio.file.Files.copy(f.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
if (!target.canExecute())
    throw new FileNotFoundException("chrome.exe copy did not work!");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", target.getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: This is basically thesame code as in the OP's question. And it won't work if the chrome driver is indide the jar.

Comment: @SiKing - I'm afraid that this didn't work for me.  Though it works when executed from Eclipse, the code when executed from the jar gives a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right and I was wrong. You cannot execute files in a jar, but you can manipulate them as files. I have edited my code.